# Me marca error este código en c :(

Tags: c, condiciones

Estoy haciendo una función que muestre el triangulo de pascal pero me lanza este error al ejecutar -> if ($?) { gcc FuncionesSinPP.c -o FuncionesSinPP } ; if ($?) { .\FuncionesSinPP }

```
void pascal(){
    int matriz[10][10], i, c=0, f=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 55; i++){
        if(c==0){
            matriz[f][c] = 1;
            c++;
        }
        else if(c==f){
            matriz[f][c] = 1;
            f++;
            c = 0;
        }
        else{
            matriz[f][c] = matriz[f - 1][c] + matriz[f - 1][c - 1];
            c++;
        }
    }
    c = 0;
    f = 0;
    for (f = 0; f < 10; f++){
        printf("%*i", matriz[f], 10 / f);
        }
}
```

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que quieres declarar las variables i, c y f en la misma línea que el array. Trata de mover eso a una línea aparte como `int i, c = 0, f = 0;`

Comment: ¿Qué error? Parece que el error no está en el código C, sino en un script de compilación, pero no está claro cómo lo intentas compilar/ejecutar (si estás usando algún IDE por ejemplo, sistema operativo, compilador usado...)

Comment: ¿Qué error te lanza? No has puesto ningún mensaje de error en la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Valida que puedas invocar a tu función pascal dentro de tu método principal creando su declaración al principio

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pascal();

int main() {  
    pascal();  
    return 0;  
}
    
    
void pascal(){  
    printf("Dentro de funcion");  
    ...
}
```

Lo segundo que te sugiero es que analices tu codigo, nunca se ejecuta la parte del else if dentro del ciclo, analiza tu algoritmo y realiza las modificaciones necesarias

```
...  
//nunca entra aqui porque f nunca se incrementa, por ende c y f nunca son iguales
else if(c==f){  
...  
}
```